# unable to get x-auth-token using spring security and CORS

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

How can I obtain the `x-auth-token` from CORS/Spring security?

I am using Angular 4 and it is not returning the `x-auth-token`. Just `Cache-Control`, `Expires`, and `Pragma`. In the network tab in chrome it does show all my response headers, but I am not allowed to get them via Angular's response method [Headers in Angular explained](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Headers-class.html)

```
.map((res: any) => {

                let authToken = res.headers.get("x-auth-token");
```

The above will just print `null` if I `console.log` it.

I was getting a `403()` at login until I added `CORS` configuration in spring-boot's security.

Since doing so I get a `200` in the network tab but am not allowed to get the token.

CORS config:

```
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*");
//              .allowedHeaders("x-auth-token")
//              .exposedHeaders("x-auth-token");

            }
        };
    }
```

I had to comment out:

```
 //             .allowedHeaders("x-auth-token")
    //              .exposedHeaders("x-auth-token");
```

because I would get a `403()` at login once I added them so my implementation was obviously wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a gotcha here. By default Spring CORS doesn't allow Authorization. You have had the below headers and the `x-auth-token` will be passed.

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("*")
                        .allowedHeaders("x-auth-token","Authorization","Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Access-Control-Allow-Credentials")
                        .exposedHeaders("x-auth-token","Authorization","Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Access-Control-Allow-Credentials")
                        .allowCredentials(false).maxAge(3600);

            }
        };
    }
```